# Smarty: blocks in includes or how organize widget on the site

Tags: php, html, web, smarty

I have site with many included widgets based on smarty.
It is very important to separate scripts and styles.

What I need:

page.php:

```
{extends file="template.tpl"}

{block name="css"}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page_style.css" />
{/block}

{block name="content"}

    Lalala

    {include file="cool_widget.tpl"}

    Tratata

{/block}

{block name="js"}
    <script src="page_script.js"></script>
{/block}
```

template.tpl

```
<link rel="fix.css" />
{block name="css"}{/block}

{block name="content"}{/block}

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
{block name="js"}{/block}
```

widget.tpl

```
{block name="css" append}
    <link rel="widget.css">
{/block}

{block name="js" append}
    <script src="widget.js"></script>
{/block}

<h2>COOL WIDGET HEAR</h2>
```

I know that I can't make blocks inside include, but I hope in another solutions. Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using capture. ie, in widget.tpl:

```
{capture name="js"}
<script src="widget.js"></script>
{/capture}
{$tpl_scripts[]=$smarty.capture.js scope="global"}
```

this will allow any include to put code in the $tpl_scripts array so it can be put anywhere you want in the main template; so, in template.tpl

```
{block name="js"}{/block}
{foreach $tpl_scripts as $tpl_script}
    {$tpl_script}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: That is what I need! Tnx!

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!